# Django: SQL query with distinct on model function

Tags: django, distinct

Hi Stackoverflow people,

in my current project, I have the following model structure:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    student_id = models.ForeignKey(User)
    class_a = models.ForeignKey(ClassA)
    class_b = models.ForeignKey(ClassB)
    ...

class ClassA(models.Model):
    teacher_name = models.CharField(...)

class ClassB(models.Model):
    teacher_name = models.CharField(...)
```

ClassA and ClassB are very different and only they *only* have the teacher_name in common, therefore I keep it in separate classes. 
In addition, in each project only class_a *or* class_b can contain a ForeignKey (it can not be assigned to two classes).

When I display all projects and I want to list the names of the teacher, therefore I created a little model function, which returns the teacher's name:

```
def get_teacher_name(self):
    if self.class_a:
        return self.class_a.teacher_name
    if self.class_b:
        return self.class_b.teacher_name
```

Now, I want to write a query which returns the names of teachers for a student_id and only returns the teachers name once, e.g.:
For Student X
Project      Teacher
Biology      Mrs. X
Physics      Mr. Y
(-> Math     Mr. Y should be disregarded)

**How should I structure the Django query? I would like to do 
Project.objects.filter(student_id=user.pk).values('get_teacher_name').distinct(), but this is not possible. Is there a solution for it?**

Thank you for your suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'er looking for `values` and `annotate` 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-values-clauses

Which will give you unique values for a values call.

```
import itertools

class_a_names = user.project_set.values_list('class_a__teacher_name', flat=True).annotate()
class_b_names = user.project_set.values_list('class_b__teacher_name', flat=True).annotate()
unique_teachers = set(itertools.chain(class_a_names, class_b_names))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please explain where the project_set is coming from? Thank you!

Comment: @neurix - if you have a `ForeignKey` from project to `User`, django adds reverse related model managers in the form `class_set` unless you specify a `related_name` argument to the `ForeignKey` field. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward

Comment: Is there a way to keep the pk of the teacher in the list as well? I have tried ('class_a_teacher__name', 'class_a_teacher__pk'), but pk can't be found. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Your model only shows teacher as a string field? I mistakenly wrote the query wrong, it would be values_list('class_a__teacher_name')